# Why Dafny complains about this post condition "ensures ListMap(x => x + 1, Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))) == Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil))", and how can it be fixed?

Tags: dafny

```
function method ListMap<T,X>(f : (T -> X), l : List<T>) : List<X>
    ensures ListMap(x => x + 1, Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))) == Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil))
{
    match l {
        case Nil => Nil
        case Cons(n, l') => Cons(f(n), ListMap(f, l'))
    }
}
```

Dafny raises two complaint here.

1. about "case Nil": A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
2. about "ensure...": This postcondition might not hold on a return path.

This snippet is from the book "Introducing Software Verification with Dafny Language: Proving Program Correctness", but I can't find the Errata for it.

Comment: Please don't put those details into the **title**. Phrase a meaningful title and put all the details in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here that you can solve at once:

The ensures won't terminate if computed (in an imaginary ghost environment) because you provide it as an intrinsic postcondition, so you will get into trouble.
Dafny is ok to ensure something about the output of the current function, but for everything other call to the function itself, it has to prove termination.

What you provide is an example of a postcondition, not a fact that ought to be known by every user of your `ListMap` function.

The solution is to refactor your ensures in a lemma:

```
datatype List<T> = Nil | Cons(t: T, tail: List<T>)

function method ListMap<T,X>(f : (T -> X), l : List<T>) : List<X>
{
    match l {
        case Nil => Nil
        case Cons(n, l') => Cons(f(n), ListMap(f, l'))
    }
}

lemma ListMapExample()
  ensures ListMap(x => x + 1, Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))) == Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil))
{
}
```